# Swift Update Issue: Cannot convert value of Type '(parameters: [AnyHashable: Any]!) -> Bool'

Tags: swift, dictionary

I took over a Swift 2 source code that need a few updates. So far I managed to get 90% of the build errors and warnings solved on my way to Swift 4. But this keeps bugging me and I don't find a solution to fix it. What would be the right syntax here?

The JLRoute call to
`JLRoutes.addRoute("login", handler: { (parameters: [AnyHashable: Any]!) -> Bool in`

results in

`Cannot convert value of Type '(parameters: [AnyHashable: Any]!) -> Bool' to expected argument type (([String : Any]) -> Bool)?'`

Full Context:

```
   JLRoutes.addRoute("login", handler: { (parameters: [AnyHashable: Any]!) -> Bool in

        let params = parameters as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        let authCode:String! = params["authkey"] as String
        if authCode != nil { 
                      [...]
                    }
                }
                .responseString { (request, response, string, error) in
                    println(string)
            }
                return true

            } else {

                self.authError()
                return false

            }
    })

    return true
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: just try to replace 'AnyHashable' in line 1 with String

Comment: Did you actually try doing what the error message tells you to do? It tells you exactly what's the new signature of that function, so if you make that correction, your code should compile just fine.

Comment: Haha... It was a long night... I kept fiddeling with `-> Bool` part